# Spotify sync to same location?

Tags: data-synchronization, spotify

I have multiple user accounts from one computer, running Yosemite.

Using same Spotify username, I'd like to sync songs offline and cache in the same path. To achieve this, I tried aliasing `/Users/Shared/Library/Cache/com.spotify.client` to each user's `~/Library/Cache/com.spotify.client`.

I noticed, however, even after one user finishes syncing, Spotify still attempts to download the songs.

What can I do to use Spotify client's cached data from the same location, so that I don't have to duplicate files for each user?

Note:
`/Users/Shared/Libarary/Cache/com.spotify.client`'s permission is 770 and all users attempting to access this folder is associated with the owner group to this folder (recursively).

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using apps in the one partition on the other. I erased the /Applications folder on one partition and symlinked the master /Applications folder in the other to the root of the partition it was erased from.

So, you could delete the com.spotify.client in all the users but one which will be the master, and then do something like this in terminal.

```
ln -s /Users/<master>/Library/Cache/com.spotify.client /Users/<nonmaster/Library/Cache/com.spotify.client
```

Not positive this will work, but assuming the permissions are correct, it might.